# How to deal with correlated response variables

Tags: correlation, normalization

I have five response variables measured at $2$ different times and I would like to know on which variables there is an improvement.

I could simply divided the newest responses on the old ones and simply count how many times this is greater than 1, however the response variables are correlated. For example, if on variable 1 there is an improvement, it is also very likely that variable 3 also shows an improvement since they are correlated. How can I find a way to calculate 'fairly' (i.e. taking into account the correlations and the improvements expected due to other response variables) how much the subjects improved on the response variables?

Comment: Improvement in which sense? There is not nearly enough information here for an answer! Please tell us much more about the applied problem, in the language of the application.

Comment: So at $T1$ the each subject has five testresults measuring their ability on some task. At $T2$ this is done again. When looking at the improvements of the subject on each task it is to be expected that the improvements are correlated; i.e. when the subject improves his score on one test, you could expect the improvement on another score. How can I remove this correlation and determine fairly (without correlations) how much someone improved their scores.

Comment: Please give us much more details about your setup (and add new information as an edit to the question, not as comments! That way your question also gets more visibility---it returns to the front page.  For instance, how many subjects.  Tell us the whole story, in the language of the application! Then we can translate to statistics.